# How to handle long lasting Microsoft Cognitive Services Text-To-Speech calls in Twilio Flow

Tags: twilio, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

Calling a .net core based webapi from Twilio flow fails due to the fact that, because the underlying call of the webapi to Microsoft cognitive service lasts more than 5 seconds. any idea on how to make the call perform faster?

I have created a .net core based WebAPI controller that generates mp3 file that is generated by Microsoft Cognitive speech-to-text service. working great.
However, when calling it from a Twilio flow, the flow fails due to the fact that the tts service takes about more than 5 seconds to complete. The first phase - getting an access token from MS takes about 2.5 seconds, and than the tts itself takes about 3 seconds. 5 seconds is the maximum that Twilio allows for a call to return, so it fails.

any idea on how to manage the Cognitive service access token (valid for 10 minutes, by Microsoft) so it will be regenerated in parallel, so I won't have to spend 2.5 seconds every call?

I can't use Twilio's text-to-speech service since Twilio do not support Hebrew (they support Hebrew only for speech-to-text).

```
public class AzureSSAuthentication
    {
        public string subscriptionKey;
        private string tokenFetchUri;

        public AzureSSAuthentication(string tokenFetchUri, string subscriptionKey)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tokenFetchUri))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tokenFetchUri));
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subscriptionKey))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(subscriptionKey));
            }
            this.tokenFetchUri = tokenFetchUri;
            this.subscriptionKey = subscriptionKey;
         }

        public async Task<string> FetchTokenAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", this.subscriptionKey);
                UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(this.tokenFetchUri);

                var result = await client.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
                return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
/////////////// Controller    

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TTSController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values/SomethingToSay
        [HttpGet("{text}")]
        [Route("Say")]
        public async Task<FileContentResult> Get(string text)
        {
            string accessToken;
            AzureSSAuthentication auth = new AzureSSAuthentication("https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken", "<MyToken>");
            //try
            //{

            accessToken = await auth.FetchTokenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                string host = "https://westeurope.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1";
                string body = @"<speak version='1.0' xmlns='https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='he-IL'>" +
                                "<voice name='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (he-IL, Asaf)'>" +
                                text + "</voice></speak>";
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
                    {
                        // Set the HTTP method
                        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

                        request.RequestUri = new Uri(host);

                        request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/ssml+xml");

                        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                        request.Headers.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                        request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "sayWhat");
                        request.Headers.Add("X-Microsoft-OutputFormat", "riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm");
                        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
                        {
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            // Asynchronously read the response
                            using (var dataStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                            {
                                byte[] dataByteArray = new byte[dataStream.Length];
                                dataStream.Read(dataByteArray, 0, (int)dataStream.Length);
                                return File(dataByteArray, "audio/mpeg", "audio.mp3");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            //}
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
            //    return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            //}
        }
    }
```

It just takes too long.

Comment: Have your server regenerate token via cron job, and store in cache, and fetch token from your server.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at doing something very similar and I am concerned about the time for the MS services also. I am also dealing with text-to-speech. The flow I was considering was to call the MS Cognitive services prior to call and temporarily store the MP3. Once the call is complete, delete the MP3 file. This way you already have the MP3 file prior to the even making the call.